# Eclipse template to Insert javadoc to an existing method

Tags: java, eclipse, templates, editor

Having an existing Java method like:

```
public int someMethod(String arg1, int arg2) {
    //do something

    return 0;
}
```

I want to create a template (named myDoc), in eclipse. When I type it above a method and hit enter it should give me:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param arg1
 * @param arg2
 * @customAt
 * @return
 */
public int someMethod(String arg1, int arg2) {
    //do something

    return 0;
}
```

I know it happens when you type /** and hit enter, but I want to put custom @s and placeholders: above the first @param, after @param names to put descriptions and after the return to describe what is returned.

And at the end of typing over placeholders I would have this:

```
/**
 * My method that does something
 * @param arg1 must be a valid string
 * @param arg2 must be greater than 0
 * @customAt my description
 * @return the code of...
 */
public int someMethod(String arg1, int arg2) {
    //do something

    return 0;
}
```

I'm aware of bad comments and I know that in some cases it could be useful like in an API, the method above is just an example.

I just want to know how to do this. I've been playing with plugin development, I writen the plugin sample in [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20100414054049/http://dev.eclipse.org/blogs/jdtui/2007/12/04/text-templates-2/). In the sample you write a template variable that I think could be the way, but I'm stucked in the resolve method of **org.eclipse.jface.text.templates.TemplateVariableResolver**. I thought I could access the position of the cursor and that I could detect a method nearby to insert the javadoc.

Is this the path?

Answer (score 0):

You can change default method javadoc template.

`Window` -> `Preferences` -> `Java` -> `Code Style` -> `Code Template`, expand the `Comments` section, select `Methods` and click `Edit...` button.

Comment: ok, I didn't explain that I wanted it dynamically. I'll edit it.

Comment: so, I tried to add custom variables, like ${objective} before ${tags} but it yields an error "Variable objective doesn't exist". I would like to insert placeholders to navigate with "TAB".

Comment: What do you mean placeholders?

Comment: Could you explain what values do you want to be inserted dynamically?

Comment: placeholders are the variables in templates that you can navigate by TAB key. I've found a possible solution but right now I can't access the source code to put the solution here. In two days I'll do this. Thanks for now.